# Calling a method (server code) from another's method stub (client code)

Tags: javascript, performance, meteor

For performance reasons, I want to call a Meteor method from another's method stub (client-only code), but I want the called method to run on server-side too

Seems like `methodBar` below runs only on client-side. Is this by design? Is there a way around it?

```
const methodFoo = new ValidatedMethod({
  // name, validate not important
  run() { 
    // ...some common code here server&client...
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
      // ...several rather expensive mongo queries, must be client-only...
      if (miniMongoResultsSaySo) Meteor.call('methodBar'); 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think it should call the method on the server, are you sure it's spelt right?

Comment: I thought so too :) But it's not calling it

Comment: Where and how are you defining `methodBar`?

Comment: @NFab: `methodBar` is defined as a ValidatedMethod in a file that is accessible both to client and server. I also tried in a server-only file, but it didn't help, the method would just not be called (no error)

Answer (score 0):

Meteor seems really stubborn in separating client and server in methods!

I could make it loose the awareness of `methodBar` being called by `methodFoo` via a Tracker dependency. Fight fire with fire and Meteor with Meteor :)

```
const barNeedsToRun = new Tracker.Dependency;
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Tracker.autorun((computation) => {
    barNeedsToRun.depend();
    if (!computation.firstRun) methodBar.call();
  }
}
```

Then in `methodFoo` I changed the `Meteor.call` with `barNeedsToRun.changed()`